# `ls /users/applications` is not listing my applications on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, php, ls

I would like to install xdebug here on my Mac (Macbook pro 8,1 13" running OS X 10.6.6), but I need to get into my applications folder in order to get to my phpize file.

When I type `% cd /users/applications` in my terminal it sure takes me to my applications folder, but then when I type `ls` the terminal returns some unique number between curly brackets followed by `Applications.localized` while I was expecting a list of the contents of applications.

What's happening?

Answer (score 12):

try `cd /Applications` and then `ls`

Comment: This is correct. By default applications in OSX are stored in /Applications. Also, "ls /Applications" will provide you with the same results.

Answer (score 4):

`/users/applications` is not likely to be your Applications folder. The main Mac Application folder is `/Applications`. Home folders are stored in `/Users` (so one would expect `/Users/applications` to be the home folder for the user with short username `applications`). You might have a folder called Applications in your home folder (i.e. `/Users/[yourusername]/Applications`, or `~/Applications` for short) - CrossOver puts stuff there, for instance. Finally, Unix-style command line programs are stored in a variety of places (some of which are hidden in the Finder) such as `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`, more or less corresponding to [the Unix directory structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_directory_structure).

As an alternative, if you have access in the Finder to the folder containing the file you want, you can add it to a command line by simply dragging it onto the Terminal window. For instance, to `cat` a file you would type `cat` (note the trailing space), then drag the file onto the Terminal window from the Finder. It will be replaced with its full path, and you can then run the command.

Bear in mind that you don't need to be in the same directory as a file to reference it - just provide a full path (i.e one that begins with `/`) or use `../` to refer to a relative parent directory (but beyond one or two levels the latter quickly gets confusing).